# Could my keyboard have been damaged by my USB hub if I used the incorrect AC adapter?

Tags: usb, keyboard

I purchased a USB Hub recently due to a lack of USB ports on my machine.

Yesterday I plugged it into my computer and attached my mouse and keyboard to the hub. This morning the peripherals kept on disconnecting so I disconnected them from the hub and directly to the computer's USB ports. They stopped disconnecting.

However, none of my keyboard's lights will turn on at all. It recognizes keypresses though. Upon closer inspection I found that the power adapter I had connected to my USB hub was 6V/400 mA, while the instructions say 5V/3A. When I disconnect the adapter the peripherals perform just fine, apart from the keyboard lighting.

It was only one day - how likely is it that the USB hub damaged my keyboard? What are some possible solutions to fix the lighting? I've tried reinstalling drivers to no avail.

Comment: The keyboard did not *"short out"*.  (Do you understand what an electrical short is?) A short typically leads to current overdraw and burning components.  USB is specified for only a 5% overvoltage tolerance, i.e. 5.25V.  A 20% overvoltage most likely caused a (sensitive) component to fail just like a ***fuse*** (and create an *open* circuit rather than a *short* circuit).

Comment: I understand electrical circuits as well as you.

Comment: @sawdust thanks for the response. Sorry, my understanding of electronics is rather poor. I just smelled my keyboard, there was a pretty faint smell of burnt plastic, but no exterior damage or smoke. How serious would you estimate this probable fuse failure to be? Do you have any suggestions for a course of action to fix this?

Comment: Keyboards have a battery; USB ports have power. That could have been the issue. An open fuse does not cause a smell but an electrical failure does and that was the point in my post.

Comment: @John are you responding to me? To clarify, it's a wired keyboard, connected via cable. I thought only wireless keyboards had batteries, and that the cable supplied power?

Comment: The variety of keyboard was not initially clear. Most keyboards today have batteries in them but a pure wired one may not. Still, the smell you spoke of comes from electrical current (at least in my experience)

Comment: @BobJohnson *"my understanding of electronics..."* -- Too often *"short"* is used in place of (electrical) "failure", but the words are not synonymous.  You would need to open it up for further diagnosis.  Because the USB spec limits power, a USB keyboard is not going to have an actual fuse.  What failed was some electrical component(s) that had to sacrifice itself (like a fuse) because it was most sensitive to the overvoltage.  Locating the burned component(s) could be easy, but identification and replacement could require expertise.

Comment: An example of "failure" due to overvoltage is flashbulbs, if you're old enough to remember what that is.  Or apply too much voltage to an incandescent bulb.

Comment: The keyboard is likely damaged - specifically it sounds to me like the LEDs were driven to hard and burnt out.  My guess is its a cheap keyboard. Just buy another one.  This is not a driver issue.